# dynamic templateUrl with param using angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a route to handle creation, modification, view and list of users like this :

```
angular
  .module('abcApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('user.add', {
        url: '/mgt/user/add',
        templateUrl: 'views/mgt_user/add.html',
        controller: 'MgtUserCtrl'
      })
      .state('user.view', {
        url: '/mgt/user/view/:userId',
        templateUrl: 'views/mgt_user/view.html',
        controller: 'MgtUserCtrl'
      })
      .state('user.list', {
        url: '/mgt/user/list',
        templateUrl: 'views/mgt_user/list.html',
        controller: 'MgtUserCtrl'
      });
  });
```

I want to use one route where I can pass the `mode` as param and get the right `templateUrl`:

```
angular
  .module('abcApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('userMangement', {
        url: '/mgt/user/:mode/:userId',
        templateUrl: 'views/mgt_user/' + $routeParams.mode + '.html',
        controller: 'MgtUserCtrl'
      });
  });
```

`mode` can be : `view`, `edit`, `list`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use templateProvider.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('userManagement', {
        url: '/mgt/user/:mode/:userId',
        controller: 'MgtUserCtrl',
        templateProvider: ['$route', '$templateCache', '$http', function($route, $templateCache, $http) {
            var url = '/views/mgt_user/' + $route.current.params.mode + '.html';
            $http.get(url, {cache: $templateCache}).then(function(html) {
                return html;
            });
        }]
 })
```

You cannot use $routeparams here becuase $routeParams is available after $routeChangeSuccess event.